# Rest request socket timeout on client - what happens to remote request in webservice

Tags: java, rest, http

I have created an java web application that calls an external webservice.

It is set to have a 45 second socket timeout (this timeout corresponds to time waiting for the response) on each service call.

There are times when the remote web service takes more than 45 seconds to respond and there is a socket timeout. It's inusual but it can happen.

My question/confusion is if I have a timeout on the client application how whappebs to that request on the webservice.

From my observations I think what is happening is that the request lives on in the web service until it's finished but then there is nothing waiting for the response anymore.

Is that consistent with normal behaviour? Should that be handled in the web service somehow? I.e.  Is there a way in the web service to know that the client application is no longer listening and to stop processing.

Also what happens to the lost request?

I'm asking this because I don't want to cause resource leaks or hung threads in the web service

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The web service will ultimately encounter a 'connection reset' when sending the response, and the container will recover correctly.

Comment: Does the connection reset happen after the request is complete and it find that nothing is waiting for the response? I.e. Does the work continue on in the web service until it's done?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a restTemplate , bump up the time on :
rest.service.connection.timeout ; Try setting this to 30 seconds.